How do I use gestures inside of a Compositor Layer in Vision OS?
I'm rendering a scene using Metal and I have a custom renderer that's passed into a CompositorLayer. I want to use gestures something like
 .onTapGesture {
      print("test")
  }

Currently, the problem is that I can't wrap the CompositorLayer in a view, so I don't have access to the gestures API. How can I get access to the gestures API? Ideally, I want the model/mesh in the scene to act like the view.
   ImmersiveSpace(id: "ImmersiveSpace") {
      CompositorLayer(configuration: ContentStageConfiguration()) { layerRenderer in
        let renderer = Renderer(layerRenderer)
        Context.render.layerRenderer = layerRenderer
        Context.state.scene = GameScene()
        renderer.startRenderLoop()
      }
    }.immersionStyle(selection: .constant(.full), in: .full)

Ideally I'd like the code to look something like this
struct Model {
    onTapGesture() {
     
    }
}


You can't use the built in gestures provided by SwiftUI. So you need to manually figure out gestures via HandTrackingProvider.
@MainActor
class HandGesture: ObservableObject, @unchecked Sendable {
  let session = ARKitSession()
  var handTracking = HandTrackingProvider()
  var worldTracking = WorldTrackingProvider()
  @Published var latestHandTracking: HandsUpdates = .init(left: nil, right: nil)
 
  
  func start() async {
    do {
      if HandTrackingProvider.isSupported {
        print("ARKitSession starting.")
        try await session.run([handTracking, worldTracking])
      }
    } catch {
      print("ARKitSession error:", error)
    }
  }
  
  func publishHandTrackingUpdates() async {
    for await update in handTracking.anchorUpdates {
      switch update.event {
      case .updated:
        // Do work here
      default:
        break
      }
    }
  }
  
  func monitorSessionEvents() async {
    for await event in session.events {
      switch event {
      case .authorizationChanged(let type, let status):
        if type == .handTracking && status != .allowed {
          // Stop the game, ask the user to grant hand tracking authorization again in Settings.
        }
      default:
        print("Session event \(event)")
      }
    }
  }
}



You can use the onspatialevent API on the LayerRenderer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/compositorservices/layerrenderer/4245856-onspatialevent
